# Finding the axes of an ellipse from deformation of a circle

Tags: algebraic-geometry, conic-sections

Consider a circle inscribed in a square (radius of circle equals half the height of the square). This figures are deformed so that the square is now a parallelogram with height equal to the original, and its base parallel and equal in length to the base of the original square. The inclined side of the parallelogram forms an angle whose tangent is $\gamma$ with the line normal to the base (a vertical line). The circle deforms into an ellipse, tangent to the parallelogram at its side's midpoints, with semiaxes $a>b$.
I know that the relationship between the semiaxes lenghts and the angle $\gamma$ can be obtained from the following equation:
$$
a^2,b^2 = \frac{\gamma^2+2±\gamma\sqrt{\gamma^2+4}}{2}\space\space\space\space equation \space1
$$
In an old text I found the forms:
$$
\gamma=\frac{a-b}{\sqrt{ab}}\space\space\space\space equation\space 2
$$
and 
$$
a,b=\frac{±\gamma+\sqrt{\gamma^2+4}}{2}\space\space\space\space equation\space 3
$$
But I can't get algebraically from equation 1 to any of the other two, even if when I try them with the same parameters gives the same results (example, setting a value for $\gamma$ and obtaining $a$ and $b$ in equation 1, gives the same $a$ and $b$ in equation 3; and using these values for $a$ and $b$ in equation 2 gives the correct value for $\gamma$).
Does anyone can relate these equations algebraically so that I am sure that I can use them indistinctly? Thanks

Comment: It looks like $\gamma$ in your first equation is some sort of skew factor rather than an angle. Are you sure that the $\gamma$ in the other equation means the same thing?

Comment: Actually, it might be a good idea to explain how you get that first equation because it looks to me like the r.h.s. is actually the *reciprocal* of the squares of the semi-axis lengths.

Comment: Sorry, $\gamma$ is actually the tangent to the angle mentioned before, not the angle. I edited so it stands correct. I am 100% sure it is the same factor in all the equations. Regarding equation 1, it results from solving the following using Baskara: $x^4-x^2(\gamma^2+2)+1=0$ (where $x$ is the radius of any of the two circles that are tangent to the ellipse -i.e. either the major semiaxis $a$ or the minor semiaxis $b$). I do not understand why you consider the r.h.s. as the reciprocals.

Comment: Just square equation 3 to get equation 1.

Comment: My mistake. I looked at the eigenvalues of the transformed quadratic form, which are equal to $1/a^2$ and $1/b^2$, respectively, but didn’t notice that in this case they are themselves reciprocals of each other, so can just be swapped to get the squares of the semi-axis lengths.

Comment: @TonyK thanks! it was pretty straightforward... but I hadn't see it. However let me ask you what happens with the ± during transformation. Why in one equation it is ahead of $\gamma$ and in the other it is before the term with the square root? During transformation I simply lost it due to squaring. Thanks again

Comment: @PMacmutton: that's straightforward algebra. Do each case ($\pm$) separately if it helps.

Comment: By the way, you should use `\tag` to label equations instead of trying to insert a bunch of white space yourself. Also, it might be better to use `\pm` instead of the `±` character, although the appear to render the same in my browser.

Comment: @TonyK sorry, you are right, ... square of binomial with a rest... I didn't mean to bother. If I may be so bold, I still could use help to relate equation 2 and 3.

Comment: Well, from equation 3 you get that $ab=1$. So equation 2 reduces to $\gamma=a-b$, which is immediate from equation 3 (assuming w.l.o.g. that $a \ge b$).

Comment: @TonyK thank you, I appreciate your help very much. regards